# date() is going crazy

Tags: php, date

I try to use date() function

But when I reload the page the displayed time does not make sense. It goes goes forward and backward.

Does anyone know what is wrong ?

```
<?php

 echo date("H:m:s");

?>
```

Comment: Read the manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php  There are plenty of examples that show date("H:i:s")

Answer (score 5):

`m` is for month. `i` is for minutes:

```
<?php

 echo date("H:i:s");

?>
```

Comment: I know 
I used i but i wrote m in my post

The probleme remains anyway